# Auto SSO over Windows

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

For a internal website, I want a automatic single-sign-on. Which means: The user dosen't need to type in any data. 
If there are no data about the user: Fallback to a basic-auth.

Its possible, because a other application is able to get the windows-username (Apache has a function for it).

But in ASP, its not working. These ideas failed for me:

1. **Enable windows-auth for IIS** Failed because the mechanism open a prompt-field for user/pass -> Not the requirement.
2. **Lookup user-ip/hostname via LDAP** Failed because our AD-server dosn't provide any details about the IP (= networkAddress)

Comment: Is this computer part of an AD domain?

Comment: Assuming you use IE, Option 1) will work if your site is considered to be in the intranet zone and/or auto-login with current credentials is enabled for the security zone.

Comment: @Amy Yes, it is.

Comment: Then `negotiate` auth should work automatically.  If you're using IE and getting the password prompt, the site needs to be added to the appropriate zone for IE to consider it "safe".

Comment: `Negotiate`is selected as first provider - not working.